# What files to include in Autotools distribution

Tags: git, wxwidgets, travis-ci, autotools, wxformbuilder

I have started a new project using wxWidgets and autotools. The wxWidgets forms are built with wxFormBuilder, so the source files for the forms are auto-generated.

Should the form files (.h, .cpp) be included in distributions?
If not, should wxFormBuilder be?

Should the form files be stored in the repository (I'll be using GitHub).

I also plan on using travis-ci in case that affects how I should approach this.

I'm pretty new to all these tools so any advice welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are auto-generated by `Makefile.am` rules, and wxFormBuilder is part of your build-time dependencies (it sounds like it is), then you should not include them in the tarball or in the repository.

You would want to add them to `BUILT_SOURCES` though.